# Why does a FLOAT give me a more accurate result than a DECIMAL?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, relational-database

I am looking for a division result that is extremely accurate.

This SQL returns the following results:

```
SELECT (CAST(297282.26  AS DECIMAL(38, 30)) / CAST(495470.44 AS DECIMAL(38, 30))) AS ResultDecimal
```

[image]

```
SELECT (CAST(297282.26 AS FLOAT) / CAST(495470.44 AS FLOAT)) AS ResultFloat
```

[image]

Here is the accurate result from WolframAlpha:
[image]
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=297282.26%2F495470.44

I was under the impression that DECIMAL would be more accurate than FLOAT:

*"Because of the approximate nature of the float and real data types, do not use these data types when exact numeric behavior is required, such as in financial applications, in operations involving rounding, or in equality checks. Instead, use the integer, decimal, money, or smallmoney data types."*

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx

Why does the FLOAT calculation give me a result more accurate than when using DECIMAL?

Comment: Float gives you a more **accurate** number but does not give you a **precise** number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the best precision to be when you use:

```
SELECT (CAST(297282.26  AS DECIMAL(15, 9)) / CAST(495470.44 AS DECIMAL(24, 2))) AS ResultDecimal
```

This gives a result of

> 0.599999991926864496699338915153

I think the actual value (to 100 digits) is:

> 0.5999999919268644966993389151530412187657451370862810705720405842980259326873264124495499670979362562...

Please bear in mind SQL Server defines the maximum precision and scale for division as:

> max precision = (p1 - s1 + s2) + MAX(6, s1 + p2 + 1) -- up to 38
>
> max scale = MAX(6, s1 + p2 + 1)

Where p1 & p2 are the precision of the two numbers and s1 & s2 are the scale of the numbers.

In this case the maximum precision is (15-9+2) + MAX(6, 9+24+1) = 8 + 34 = 42.

However SQL Server only allows a maximum precision of 38.

The maximum scale = MAX(6, 9+24+1) = 34

Comment: Steve, you are spot on. I did not do the math for the decimal output correctly. Having decided what my minimum requirements are for Precision and Scale for the inputs, and what the desired Precision and Scale should be for the output, (and taking the Max values into account) the rest is relatively easy. The full set of Precision and Scale calculations are available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms190476.aspx This has been very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully you already understand that just because the `FLOAT` version presents more numbers after the decimal point, doesn't necessarily mean that those are the **true** numbers. This is about *precision*, not *accuracy*.

It is the `CAST` function itself that causes this loss of precision, not the difference between the `FLOAT` and `DECIMAL` data types.

To demonstrate this, compare your previous results to the result of this:

```
SELECT 297282.26  / 495470.44  AS ResultNoCast
```

[image: Result without using CAST function]

In my version of the query, the presence of a decimal point in the literal numbers tells SQL Server to treat the values as `DECIMAL` datatype, with appropriate length and precision as determined by the server. The result is more precise than when you `CAST` explicitly to `DECIMAL`.

A clue to the reason for this can be found hidden in the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(SQL.105).aspx) of the `CAST` function, under **Truncating and Rounding Results**:

> When you convert data types that differ in decimal places, sometimes the result value is truncated and at other times it is rounded. The following table shows the behavior.

```
From     | To       | Behavior
numeric  | numeric  | Round
```

So the fact that each separate literal value is treated as a `NUMERIC` (same thing as `DECIMAL`) on the way in, and is being casted to `NUMERIC`, causes rounding.

Anticipating your next question a little, if you want a more precise result from the `NUMERIC`/`DECIMAL` datatype, you just need to tell SQL Server that each component of the calculation is more precise:

```
SELECT 297282.26000000  / 495470.44000000  AS ResultSuperPrecise
```

[image]

This appears (from experimentation) to be the most precise I can get: either adding or removing a 0 from either the numerator or denominator makes the result less precise. I'm at a loss to explain why that is, because the result is only 23 digits to the right of the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't give you a more accurate result. I say that because the value is an approximate and not all values will be available to stored in a float. On the other side of that coin though is that float has the possibility of a lot more precision. The maximum precision of a decimal/numeric is 38. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

When you look at float though the maximum precision is 53. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx

Comment: Precision for float and decimal mean different things. Float - "Where n is the number of bits that are used to store the mantissa of the float number". Decimal - "The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored" For a float a value (n) of 53 indicates a precision of only 15 digits. For a decimal the precision (p) indicates the total number of digits and can go up to 38.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is what I think is going on.

@philosophicles -  I think you are right in that the CAST is causing the problem, but not because I am trying to "convert data types that differ in decimal places".

When I execute the following statement

```
SELECT CAST((297282.26 / 495470.44) AS DECIMAL(38, 30)) AS ResultDecimal
```

The accurate result for the calculation is

[image]

This has way more than 30 digits after the decimal point, and my data type has scale set to 30. So the CAST rounds the value, then just adds zeros to the end until there are 30 digits. We end up with this:

[image]

So the interesting thing is how does the CAST determine up to how many decimals to round or truncate the output? I am not sure, but as @philosophicles pointed out, the scale of the input effects the rounding applied on the output.

```
SELECT CAST(((297282.26/10000) / (495470.44/10000)) AS DECIMAL(38, 30)) AS ResultDecimal
```

[image]

Thoughts?

Also interesting:

> However, in simple terms, precision is lost when the input scales are
>   high because the result scales need to be dropped to 38 with a
>   matching precision drop.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/automatic-decimal-rounding-issue

> The precision and scale of the numeric data types *besides* decimal are fixed.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/automatic-decimal-rounding-issue